# Make my code faster - load CSVs into pandas dataframe on selected columns and merge them

Tags: python

I have three CSV files in the folder ending by "1251". I want to iterate through the folder, pick these files, load them in chunks into pandas dataframes and merge them with selected columns.

The file of 90MB is a breeze but the script takes 15 min to add the file of 700 MB (over 3 mil lines). The whole operation takes 20 min to finish - this being unacceptable.

Is there any way to change and accelerate the procedure? I mean load CSV to pandas dataframes in chunks and merge/append/concatenate them into one file.

This works well with small files, but it needs to be faster with big csv files. I have found many questions with good ideas, but this should work - not sure why is it so slow. 
Any ideas how to make it faster?

```
import os
import sys
import struct
import fileinput
import csv
import pandas as pd



cwd = 'C:\\Users\\'
print(cwd)
directory = (cwd + '\\FINAL\\')
directory2 = (cwd + '\\FINAL\\CSV')
print(directory)
x=pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith( "1251.csv"):
        fajl = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        print(fajl)
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(directory + '\\' + fajl + ".csv", sep=",",error_bad_lines=False, encoding='latin-1',low_memory=False, chunksize=100000):

            mylist = []
            mylist.append(chunk)
            big_data = pd.concat(mylist, axis= 0)


            big_data = big_data.fillna(value='')
            selected = big_data[['SYS', 'MANDT', 'AGR_NAME', 'OBJECT', 'AUTH', 'FIELD', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'DELETED']]

            x=x.append(selected)

            x.to_csv(directory2 + '\\' + fajl + '.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have several problems with your code.

1. Why are you reading in chunks? Can pandas not handle reading your csv's? Or was this an attempt to speed-up the code?
2. For some reason you're re-initializing the list inside your second for-loop, and in essence this code isn't doing anything beyond appending a dataframe:

   ```
       for chunk in pd.read_csv(directory + '\\' + fajl + ".csv", sep=",",error_bad_lines=False, encoding='latin-1',low_memory=False, chunksize=100000):

           mylist = []
           mylist.append(chunk)
           big_data = pd.concat(mylist, axis= 0)


           big_data = big_data.fillna(value='')
           selected = big_data[['SYS', 'MANDT', 'AGR_NAME', 'OBJECT', 'AUTH', 'FIELD', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'DELETED']]

           x=x.append(selected)
   ```
3. Assuming pandas can handle your csv's (it's not clear from your post how large each csv is), I would go about this in the following way (using pd.concat for a list containing several DataFrame's is way more efficient than append):

   ```
   import csv
   import pandas as pd    
   cwd = 'C:\\Users\\'
   print(cwd)
   directory = (cwd + '\\FINAL\\')
   directory2 = (cwd + '\\FINAL\\CSV')
   print(directory)
   my_list = []
   for file in os.listdir(directory):
       if file.endswith( "1251.csv"):
           fajl = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
           print(fajl)
           curr_df = pd.read_csv(directory + '\\' + fajl + ".csv", sep=",",error_bad_lines=False, encoding='latin-1', usecols=['SYS', 'MANDT', 'AGR_NAME', 'OBJECT', 'AUTH', 'FIELD', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'DELETED'])
           curr_df = curr_df.fillna(value='')
           my_list.append(curr_df)
   x = pd.concat(my_list)
   x.to_csv(directory2 + '\\' + fajl + '.csv', sep=',', index=False)
   ```
4. Assuming you really do have to read in chunks:

   ```
   import os
   import sys
   import struct
   import fileinput
   import csv
   import pandas as pd



   cwd = 'C:\\Users\\'
   print(cwd)
   directory = (cwd + '\\FINAL\\')
   directory2 = (cwd + '\\FINAL\\CSV')
   print(directory)
   x = []
   for file in os.listdir(directory):
       if file.endswith( "1251.csv"):
           fajl = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
           print(fajl)

           for chunk in pd.read_csv(directory + '\\' + fajl + ".csv", sep=",",error_bad_lines=False, encoding='latin-1',low_memory=False, chunksize=100000):

               x.append(chunk['SYS', 'MANDT', 'AGR_NAME', 'OBJECT', 'AUTH', 'FIELD', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'DELETED'])
   big_data = pd.concat(x, axis=0)
   big_data = big_data.fillna(value='')
   big_data.to_csv(directory2 + '\\' + fajl + '.csv', sep=',', index=False)
   ```

Comment: Thank you, it was marginally faster. 3 files of 90+730+80MB took 16 min with `append` method and 13min with `concat` method. I have to search for some alternative. I guess that I will firstly clean the csv files of undesired columns and merge them together with `dask`...

Comment: Are you going with the chunking method? Try without it if you can...I think that's the key to be honest.

Comment: I have to avoid that chunking when combined with selected columns I guess... But the third option works fine, although I am a bit worried about 2+GB files...